# How do I scroll the text on my div with limited height?

Tags: javascript

So I have blocks of paragraphs that doesnt fit on my page, my solution is to have a scrolling method so when the user hovers on the down arrow, it will scroll down the paragraph and reveal more text.

[alt text http://www.picamatic.com/view/2446369_scroll/](http://www.picamatic.com/view/2446369_scroll/)

So I attached an image of my project, as you can see I have scroll down and scroll up buttons.

Here's the HTML file of my project:

```
<div id="content1" class="scrolling-content">
                <div>
                    <div id="story" style="overflow:hidden; width:40%;">
                        <h2 style="font-size:30px;">Quirino's Story</h2>
                            <p>Elpidio Quirino was a Filipino politician, and the sixth President           of the Philippines.</p>
                            <p>He was born in Vigan, Ilocos Sur to Mariano Quirino and Gregoria Rivera, Quirino spent his early years in Aringay, La Union. He received secondary education at Vigan High School, then went to Manila where he worked as junior computer in the Bureau of Lands and as property clerk in the Manila police department. He graduated from Manila High School in 1911 and also passed the civil service examination, first-grade.</p>

                            <p>Quirino attended the University of the Philippines. In 1915, he earned his law degree from the university's College of Law, and was admitted to the bar later that year. He was engaged in the private practice of law until he was elected as member of the Philippine House of Representatives from 1919 to 1925, then as Senator from 1925 to 1931. He then served as Secretary of Finance and Secretary of the Interior in the Commonwealth government.</p>

                            <p>In 1934, Quirino was a member of the Philippine Independence mission to Washington D.C., headed by Manuel L. Quezon that secured the passage in the United States Congress of the Tydings-McDuffie Act. This legislation set the date for Philippine independence by 1945. Official declaration came on July 4, 1946.</p>

                            <p>During the Battle of Manila in World War II, his wife, Alicia Syquia, and three of his five children were killed as they were fleeing their home.</p>

                            <p>After the war, Quirino continued public service, becoming president pro tempore of the Senate. In 1946, he was elected first vice president of the independent Republic of the Philippines, serving under Manuel Roxas. He also served as secretary of state.</p>

                            <span onmouseover = "start_scroll_up()"; onmouseout="stopscrolling";  id="up"><img src="images/arrow_up.png" /></span>
                    <span id="down" onmouseover="start_scroll_down()"; onmouseout="stopscrolling"; ><img src="images/arrow_down.png" /></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here's the Javascript file:

```
var UpdateInterval = 20;
var PixelPerInterval = 2;
var scrollInterval;

function startScrollUp() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(scrollUp, UpdateInterval);
}

function startScrollDown() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(scrollDown, UpdateInterval);

function scrollDown() {
    document.getElementById('story').scrollHeight += PixelPerInterval;
}

function scrollUp() {
    document.getElementById('story').scrollHeight -= PixelPerInterval;
}

function stop_scrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
}
```

Thanks guys!!

Comment: What's the question??? "How can I annoy my users?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended your code and produced a working example.  This is a complete html page.

```
<html><head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content1" class="scrolling-content" style="height:100px;overflow-y:auto;">

                        <h2 style="font-size:30px;">Quirino's Story</h2>
                            <p>Elpidio Quirino was a Filipino politician, and the sixth President                       of the Philippines.</p>
                            <p>He was born in Vigan, Ilocos Sur to Mariano Quirino and Gregoria Rivera, Quirino spent his early years in 

Aringay, La Union. He received secondary education at Vigan High School, then went to Manila where he worked as junior computer in the Bureau 

of Lands and as property clerk in the Manila police department. He graduated from Manila High School in 1911 and also passed the civil service 

examination, first-grade.</p>

                            <p>Quirino attended the University of the Philippines. In 1915, he earned his law degree from the university's 

College of Law, and was admitted to the bar later that year. He was engaged in the private practice of law until he was elected as member of 

the Philippine House of Representatives from 1919 to 1925, then as Senator from 1925 to 1931. He then served as Secretary of Finance and 

Secretary of the Interior in the Commonwealth government.</p>

                            <p>In 1934, Quirino was a member of the Philippine Independence mission to Washington D.C., headed by Manuel L. 

Quezon that secured the passage in the United States Congress of the Tydings-McDuffie Act. This legislation set the date for Philippine 

independence by 1945. Official declaration came on July 4, 1946.</p>

                            <p>During the Battle of Manila in World War II, his wife, Alicia Syquia, and three of his five children were killed 

as they were fleeing their home.</p>

                            <p>After the war, Quirino continued public service, becoming president pro tempore of the Senate. In 1946, he was 

elected first vice president of the independent Republic of the Philippines, serving under Manuel Roxas. He also served as secretary of 

state.</p>

            </div>
                            <span onmouseover = "startScrollUp();" onmouseout="stop_scrolling();";  id="up"><img src="images/arrow_up.png" 

/></span>
                    <span id="down" onmouseover="startScrollDown();" onmouseout="stop_scrolling();" ><img src="images/arrow_down.png" /></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var UpdateInterval = 20;
var PixelPerInterval = 2;
var scrollInterval;

function startScrollUp() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){scrollUp()}, UpdateInterval);
}

function startScrollDown() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){scrollDown()}, UpdateInterval);
}
function scrollDown() {
    document.getElementById('content1').scrollTop += PixelPerInterval;
}

function scrollUp() {
    document.getElementById('content1').scrollTop -= PixelPerInterval;
}

function stop_scrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
}
</script>
</body>
```

You were close though.

Cheers,

Andrew :-)

Comment: Glad I could be of some help. :-)